# SQL Server Transactional Replication

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012

I am using SQL Server 2012 and I am investigating transactional replication and had a question on SQL Versions that can be used.

The Distribution and Publisher will be on SQL2012 Standard Edition, the database is around 200GB in size.

Is it possible to use SQL Express as the subscriber in this instance as long as I create it as a Push Subscriber?

My worries/question is that SQL Server Express has a 10GB database size limit and I am not sure if this applies to replication or not.

I hope this makes sense

Cheers
David

Comment: If you are replicating whole 200GB, then Express edition wont support that due to the database size limitation of 10GB. Out of curiosity, do you have a requirement to replicate the entire database ?

Comment: That was my concern I guess.

Comment: I am still looking into if it is a requirement to replicate the whole database as 150GB of the data are BLOBS, we are trying to move these out of the database to slower file storage but that is a project in itself. 

We are looking at using ScaleArc to service Reads from the Subscriber that will be in Hong Kong while the Writes are performed to the Publisher in London. This is to increase the user experience locally in Asia.

I am not sure currently if ScaleArc requires the full DB to be replicated yet but if not then we can look to use a subset of tables to improve the user experience.